# Can't close non-blocking UDP socket in C Fedora16

Tags: c, sockets, unix, udp, nonblocking

I built very basic UDP chat using C language and Fedora 16 OS.

When my server connect, he got 5 ports and listen to them.

My problem is: when I'm trying to connect to the server with new client but gives him port that my server don't know, I want him to exit Immediately.

I don't know how to check the "MSG_DONTWAIT" flag.

Here is my code:

**Server side:**

```
#define MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE 1024
#define SERVER_CONNECTIONS 5

// Implementation of server that manages a chat.
#include "server.h"

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)  //check if user insert more then one argument to the program
    {
        printf("Usage server <port>\n‬‬");
        fflush(stdout);
        exit (-1);
    }

/*!
========Server creation flow:========
1) create the socket
2) bind the socket to a port
3) recvfrom (read from socket)
4) sendto (close the socket)
5) close the socket
*/

//!------------------------------------- 1) create the socket-------------------------------------
//!------------------------------- 2) bind the socket to a port-----------------------------------
    int fd[SERVER_CONNECTIONS];  //socket descriptor
    int port[SERVER_CONNECTIONS];  //socket fd port
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<SERVER_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    {
        port[i] = atoi(argv[1])+i;
    }
    create_sockets(fd, port);

    char buf[MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE]; //used by read() & write()
    int maxfd = find_maxfd(fd);
    struct sockaddr_in cli;  //used by read() & write()
    int cli_len = sizeof(cli);  //used by read() & write()

    fd_set readfds;
    fd_set writefds;
    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = 1;
    int nbytes=0;

    while(1)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_ZERO(&writefds);
        for(i=0; i<SERVER_CONNECTIONS; i++)
        {
            FD_SET(fd[i], &readfds);
            FD_SET(fd[i], &writefds);
        }

        /* Now use FD_SET to initialize other fd’s that have already been returned by accept() */
        if (select(maxfd+1, &readfds, 0, 0, 0) < 0)
        {
            perror("select");
            exit(1);
        }

        for(i=0; i<SERVER_CONNECTIONS; i++)
        {
//!------------------------------- recvfrom (read from socket)-----------------------------------
            if(FD_ISSET(fd[i], &readfds))
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "ready to read from %d\n", fd[i]);
                memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf)); //init buf
                if((nbytes = recvfrom(fd[i], buf, sizeof(buf), 0 /* flags */, (struct sockaddr*) &cli, (socklen_t*)&cli_len)) < 0)
                {
                    perror("recvfrom");
                    exit(1);
                }
//!------------------------------- sendto (close the socket)-----------------------------------
                FD_ZERO(&writefds);
                FD_SET(fd[i], &writefds);

                if (select(maxfd+1, 0, &writefds, 0, &timeout) < 0)
                {
                    perror("select");
                    exit(1);
                }

                if(FD_ISSET(fd[i], &writefds))
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "ready to write to %d\n", fd[i]);
                    string_to_hex(buf);
                    if ((nbytes = sendto(fd[i], buf, strlen(buf), 0 /* flags */, (struct sockaddr*) &cli, sizeof(cli))) < 0)
                    {
                        perror("sendto");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


void create_sockets(int fd[], int port[])
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<SERVER_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    {
//!------------------------------------- 1) create the socket-------------------------------------
        if((fd[i] = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
        {
            perror("socket");
            exit(1);
        }

//!------------------------------- 2) bind the socket to a port-----------------------------------
        struct sockaddr_in srv;  //used by bind()
        srv.sin_family = AF_INET;  //use the Internet address family
        srv.sin_port = htons(port[i]);  //socket ‘fd’ to port
        srv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);  //a client may connect to any of my addresses

        if(bind(fd[i], (struct sockaddr*) &srv, sizeof(srv)) < 0)
        {
            perror("bind");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

int find_maxfd(int fd[])
{
    int i=0;
    int res=fd[0];
    for(i=1; i<SERVER_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    {
        if(fd[i]>res)
        {
            res = fd[i];
        }
    }
    return res;
}

void string_to_hex(char buf[])
{
    int buf_size = strlen(buf);

    char result[buf_size*3+1];
    memset(&result, 0, sizeof(result));
    char temp[4];

    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<buf_size-1; i++)
    {
        memset(&temp, 0, sizeof(temp));
        sprintf(temp, "%X:", (int)buf[i]);
        strcat(result, temp);
    }
    memset(&temp, 0, sizeof(temp));
    sprintf(temp, "%X", (int)buf[i]);
    strcat(result, temp);

    strcpy(buf, result);
}
```

**Client side:**

```
#define MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE 1024

// Implementation of client that will use the chat.
#include "client.h"

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    if(argc != 3)  //check if user insert more then one argument to the program
    {
        printf("Usage client <host name> <port>\n‬‬");
        fflush(stdout);
        exit(-1);
    }

/*!
========Client creation flow:========
1) create the socket
2) sendto (close the socket)
3) recvfrom (read from socket)
4) close the socket
*/

    fprintf(stderr, "please enter something: \n");

//!------------------------------------- 1) create the socket-------------------------------------
    int fd;  //socket descriptor
    if((fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in srv;  //used by sendto()

    srv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    srand ( time(NULL) );  //new random seed
    int rand_num = (rand() % 5) + atoi(argv[2]);  //
    srv.sin_port = htons(rand_num);

    char *srv_name = argv[1];
    struct hostent *hp; //ptr to host info for remote
    hp = gethostbyname(srv_name);
    if( hp == NULL)
    {
        herror("gethostbyname");
        exit(-1);
    }

    srv.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct in_addr*)(hp->h_addr))->s_addr; //set IP Address to "srv_name"

    char buf[MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE]; //used by read() & write()
    int nbytes=0;
    while(1)
    {
//!------------------------------------- 2) sendto (close the socket)-------------------------------------
        memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf)); //init buf
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin); //get input from user

        if(strcmp(buf, "quit\n") == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        if(!((strlen(buf) == 1) && (buf[1] == '\n')))
        {
            buf[strlen(buf)-1] = '\0';
        }
        //write_to_server(fd, buf, srv);
        if ((nbytes = sendto(fd, buf, strlen(buf), MSG_DONTWAIT /* flags */, (struct sockaddr*) &srv, sizeof(srv)) < 0))
        {
            perror("sendto");
            exit(1);
        }

//!------------------------------------- 3) recvfrom (read from socket)-------------------------------------
        memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf)); //init read_buf
        //read_from_server(fd, buf);
        if((nbytes = recvfrom(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0 /* flags */, 0, 0) < 0))
        {
            perror("recvfrom");
            exit(1);
        }
        if( (errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK ) )
        {
            perror("EWOULDBLOCK");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("%s\n", buf); //print result to client
        fflush(stdout);
    }
//!------------------------------------- close the socket-------------------------------------
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: UDP does not connect. Your client just shouts in the dark if it uses a wrong portnumber.

Comment: What does "when I'm trying to connect to the server with new client but gives him port that my server don't know" mean? If you need fixed ports, why aren't you fixing them at bind time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it..

You need to use connect function from client and the "MSG_DONTWAIT" flag.

then when the client connect and you type anything he exit right away..

```
//!--------------- 2) connect to the server--------------------------
if(connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*) &srv, sizeof(srv)) < 0) //connect to server "srv_name"
{
    perror("connect");
    exit(-1);
}
```